# How to Create a Table of Names and Average Numbers?

Tags: java, average, stdout

I need to write a Java program that reads in lines from standard input
with each line containing a name and three integers and then uses printf() to print a table with
a column of the names, the integers, and the average of the three integers accurate to two decimal
places. I will specify the number of names as a command-line argument and then type in at
least that number of names (along with three integers for each name). Then I would signal the end of Control Z and then Enter since I'm using Windows.

My final result should look something like this:
java Average 4

Joe 3 5 2

Tim 4 1 5

Jane 6 3 2

Jack 8 3 5

Ctrl+Z

Joe 3 5 2 3.33

Tim 4 1 5 3.33

Jane 6 3 2 3.67

Jack 8 3 5 5.33

Right now, my program is only averaging the numbers I'm entering. It isn't printing the names I entered. Can anyone give me tips on how to correct my current code? I want to keep it as simple as possible since I'm new to programming.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        String names = args [0];
        
        int count = 0;       // number input values
        double sum = 0.0;    // sum of input values

        // read data and compute statistics
        while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
            String run = StdIn.readString ();
            double value = StdIn.readDouble();
            sum += value;
            count++;
        }

        // compute the average
        double average = sum / count;

        // print results
        StdOut.print(names);
        StdOut.printf(names + "%3.2f", average);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`main(String[] args)` gets called when you first start your program. If you start the program without passing any arguments, `names` will be empty. You need to either pass in your names when you start your program, or populate `names` in the while loop with `StdIn` like you are for the other values.

Comment: I want to be able to generate any name without typing in specific names. Do I need to use an array for this, or will modifications to my current code work for that?